# BigQuery C# library access denied on Dataset

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

Our environment uses GKE for authentication, I am doing a simple call to create my client using the C# libraries for BigQuery:

```
public BigQueryClientDeligationHandler(string projectId, GoogleCredential credential = null)
{
    _client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId, credential);
}
```

Since this is GKE there is no need to supply the Google credentials because the container should already be authenticated.

I made sure the service account has the following permissions

- roles/bigquery.admin;
- roles/bigquery.dataOwner;
- roles/bigquery.dataEditor;
- roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator

When I run this:

```
var dataSet = await _bigQueryClient.GetOrCreateDatasetAsync(_datasetName);
```

It errors with:

> An unhandled exception has occurred: "The service bigquery has thrown an exception.
>
> HttpStatusCode is Forbidden.
>
> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
> Access Denied: Project  : User does not have bigquery.datasets.create permission in project . [403]
>
> Errors [
> Message [ Access Denied: Project : User does not have bigquery.datasets.create permission in ] Location[ - ]   > Reason[accessDenied] Domain[global]
> ]

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Should the admin role or dataEditor role cover this?

Comment: Can you try again after giving [bigquery.datasets.create](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#before_you_begin) IAM permission? From the error message it seems like the service account doesn't have necessary permissions to create the dataset,can you verify that.You can troubleshoot further by checking GKE and BigQuery logs.

Comment: roles/bigquery.dataOwner;
roles/bigquery.dataEditor; Both should contain bigquery.datasets.create, that is the puzzling thing.  The logs tell me nothing but the error I listed.

Comment: Does that error log message provide any information about which service account lacks the necessary permission?